# Possible to convert SomeClass<T> to SomeClass<object> where T is not "known" until runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Why I ran into this issue is shown with an example below with `KnownValueDefinition<T>` where ideally I would like to be able to output a `List<KnownValueDefinition<object>>` from a static class with a bunch of static readonly `KnownValueDefinition<T>`s

```
var reflectedFields =
    typeof(KnownValue)
    .GetFields( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public )
    .Where( p => p.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KnownValueDefinition<>) );

foreach( var fieldInfo in reflectedFields )
{
    object value = fieldInfo.GetValue( null );
    // every conversion method I've tried here fails...
}
```

where `KnownValueDefinition<T>` is basically defined as:

```
public class KnownValueDefinition<T> 
{
    // .. private members excluded for brevity
    public string Key { get { return _key; } }
    public T DefaultValue { get { return _defaultValue; } }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get better than making T object, and I don't think there's much worse than a generic where the type passed in is object.

Comment: If you sample is inline with what you want you can create instance of generic class for given type and than invoke method (may even save some reflection if you define non-generic interface with `object GetDefault()` method implemented by generic class similar to `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: @Alexei - yes this gave me an idea that works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexei's comment gave me an idea that appears to work perfectly (at least for my purposes)!:

```
public class KnownValueDefinition<T> :
      IKnownValueDefinition
    , IKnownValueDefinition<T>
{
    // .. private members excluded for brevity
    public string Key { get { return _key; } }
    public T DefaultValue { get { return _defaultValue; } }

    public KnownValueDefinition( string key, T DefaultValue )
    {
        //...construction logic
    }

    public IKnownValueDefinition<object> GetDefault()
    {
        return new KnownValueDefinition<object>( this._key, this._defaultValue );
    }
}

public interface IKnownValueDefinition
{
    IKnownValueDefinition<object> GetDefault();
}

public interface IKnownValueDefinition<out T>
{
    string Key { get; }
    T DefaultValue { get; }
}
```

and to complete this with the usage scenario:

```
var knownValueDefinitions = new List<IKnownValueDefinition<object>>();

var reflectedFields =
    typeof(KnownValue)
    .GetFields( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public )
    .Where( p => p.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KnownValueDefinition<>) );

foreach( var value in reflectedFields.Select( fieldInfo => fieldInfo.GetValue( null ) ) )
    KnownValueDefinitions.Add( ((IKnownValueDefinition)value).GetDefault() );
```

Comment: of course this incurs the cost of boxing/unboxing, but for this particular use case the results were memoized and the cache is refreshed once every 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

You can define and implement a covariant interface:

```
public interface IKnownValueDefinition<out T> 
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public T DefaultValue { get; }
}

public class KnownValueDefinition<T> : IKnownValueDefinition<T>
{
    // .. private members excluded for brevity
    public string Key { get { return _key; } }
    public T DefaultValue { get { return _defaultValue; } }
}
```

Usage:

```
var kvdSomeClass = new KnownValueDefinition<SomeClass>();
IKnownValueDefinition<object> kvdObject = kvd; // this works

// but this will not work
var kvdInt = newKnownValueDefinition<int>();
kvdObject = kvdInt;
```

[Covariance & Contravariance MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Only for generic interfaces and delegates. Per the documentation: *Only interface types and delegate types can have variant type parameters.*

Comment: Yes, I remembered that and updated accordingly, but it is still possible to do what the questioner wants by creating a simple covariant interface for his/her needs.

Comment: @Moho value types **do** inherit from `object`.

Comment: yes, value types do inherit from object, but value type to object doesn't work for covariance

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO.

Given two classes:

```
class BaseClass { ... }
class DerivedClass : BaseClass { ... }
```

and a generic class

```
class Widget<T> { ... }
```

It's instantiations

```
Widget<BaseClass> {...}
Widget<DerivedClass> { ... }
```

are pretty much treated as independent classes. You can't "upcast" like this:

```
Widget<DerivedClass> instance = new Widget<DerivedClass>() ;
Widget<BaseClass>    upcastInstance = (Widget<DerivedClass>)instance ;
```

even though it seems like a perfectl sane thing to want to do.

Further, C# (and the CLR?) has no way of saying something like

```
Widget<?> = instance = ... ;
```

to indicate that all I care about is the fact that it is some instance of `Widget<T>`, but that I don't care about the type of `T`.

There's lots of questions (and answers) on this topic: just search.